# "skip_process_on_empty" plugin does not exist

Tags: drush, 8

I'm trying to migrate entities from a D7 to a D8 site using this tut: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/migrating-taxonomy-drupal-7-to-drupal-8

When I execute the migration I get the error:

> The "skip_process_on_empty" plugin does not exist.

And then it just hangs.

I have this in my migrate yml file:

```
parent:
    -
      plugin: skip_process_on_empty
      source: parent
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: custom_taxonomy_term
```

I tried changing it to `skip_row_on_empty` but get the same error regarding "skip_process_on_empty".

Here's the contents of [mymodule]/config/install/migrate.migration.custom_taxonomy_term.yml

```
id: custom_taxonomy_term
label: Drupal 7 taxonomy terms
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - monster_migrate_7
migration_groups:
  - Drupal 7
source:
  plugin: custom_taxonomy_term
process:
  tid: tid
  vid:
    plugin: migration
    migration: custom_taxonomy_vocabulary
    source: vid
  name: name
  description: description
  weight: weight
  parent:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty  <--changed this per suggestion
      method: process
      source: parent
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: custom_taxonomy_term
  changed: timestamp
destination:
  plugin: entity:taxonomy_term
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - custom_taxonomy_vocabulary
```

And here's what I get when I try to execute it:

```
> drush migrate-manifest sites/all/modules/monster_migrate_7/manifest.yml --legacy-db-url=mysql://[user]:[pass]@localhost/monster
Running custom_taxonomy_vocabulary                                                                                                                                                    [ok]
Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'custom_taxonomy_vocabulary'                                                                                [status]
Running custom_taxonomy_term                                                                                                                                                          [ok]
The "skip_process_on_empty" plugin does not exist.                                                                                                                                    [error]
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

skip_process_on_empty and skip_row_on_empty were combined into a single plugin. Try this:

```
plugin: skip_on_empty
method: process
```

To skip a row:

```
plugin: skip_on_empty
method: row
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried that and I'm still getting the error: `The "skip_process_on_empty" plugin does not exist.` but the process ends on it's own now but no imported terms (importing vocabulary worked fine). I don't get why it's still referring to "skip_process_on_empty" in the error. I tried `drush cache-clear drush` and `drush cr` to no avail.

Comment: I updated the question with more info.

Comment: Migrations are config entities. You can't just update the files in the module, you need to update them in your active configuration too.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify? I'm still kind of a Drupal newb.

Comment: Thanks Berdir, I caught up to you... I needed to reload the configuration with `drush pm-uninstall [my_module] -y && drush en [my_module]`. Also, Proxima's answer :) Thanks!